# Delphi: ToolButton & Action - funny

Tags: delphi, button, actionlist

I have a tool button and an assigned to it action. But the action doesn't have an on click event, there is no code for a click. Therefor the button is disabled, how to change it to be enabled?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are using button as a checkbox?

Comment: If you are venturing into the wonderous world of Action Lists I can highly recommend the article "Effectively using Action Lists" by Ray Konopka (author of the Raize component suite): http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27058 He used to have three articles on his own site, but on embarcadero there is but one, but it may well be the "combined" version (don't have the originals handy).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When an action has no `OnExecute` handler, the action is always disabled. If you want to assign an action to an object, and have that object be enabled, then you need to provide an `OnExecute` handler.

The question sounds a little odd though. Why would you have a button which, when pressed, does nothing?  Do you perhaps, have an `OnClick` handler that is defined in the button rather than the action? If so then you should simply move that handler into the action and all will be well.

**Update**

Ulrich helpfully points out that the [`DisableIfNoHandler`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ActnList.TCustomAction.DisableIfNoHandler) of `TAction` can be used to change the behaviour described above. Since this has public visibility and is not published, you have to make the change in code which is why I think I forgot about it.

Comment: Thanks! A main idea of the button - is to be checked or not (true/false). There are other buttons - they have something to do :)

Comment: @David, I think you forgot about [DisableIfNoHandler](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ActnList_TCustomAction_DisableIfNoHandler.html).

Comment: Well, I learned a new bit of delphi trivia today, thanks Ulrich.